.NET framework XmlDocument doesn't implement RFC3076 (Canonical XML Version 1.0) correctly
In the RFC, section 3.4 Character Modifications and Character References, it states that the input document of:
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ATTLIST normId id ID #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST normNames attr NMTOKENS #IMPLIED>
]>
<doc>
   <text>First line&#x0d;&#10;Second line</text>
   <value>&#x32;</value>
   <compute><![CDATA[value>"0" && value<"10" ?"valid":"error"]]>
   </compute>
   <compute expr='value>"0" &amp;&amp; value&lt;"10"
?"valid":"error"'>valid</compute>
   <norm attr=' &apos;   &#x20;&#13;&#xa;&#9;   &apos; '/>
   <normNames attr='   A   &#x20;&#13;&#xa;&#9;   B   '/>
   <normId id=' &apos;   &#x20;&#13;&#xa;&#9;   &apos; '/>
</doc>

In Canonical Form, looks like this:
<doc>
   <text>First line&#xD;
Second line</text>
   <value>2</value>
   <compute>value&gt;"0" &amp;&amp; value&lt;"10" ?"valid":"error"
   </compute>
   <compute expr="value>&quot;0&quot; &amp;&amp; value&lt;&quot;10&quot;
?&quot;
valid&quot;:&quot;error&quot;">valid</compute>
   <norm attr=" '    &#xD;&#xA;&#x9;   ' "></norm>
   <normNames attr="A &#xD;&#xA;&#x9; B"></normNames>
   <normId id="' &#xD;&#xA;&#x9; '"></normId>
</doc>

Simplifying my specific use case to just a single XML node with a couple of character references in to demonstrate the issue, my code looks like this:
    var funkyXml = "<text>First line&#x0d;&#10;Second&#13; line</text>";
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
    doc.LoadXml(funkyXml);

    Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);

Which outputs the following (I've included the CR and LF character codes to illustrate where there are bytes 13 and 10:
<text>First line\r\nSecond\r line</text>

And for the avoidance of doubt, this is the actual rendered string:

So what I've found is that XmlDocument replaces the CR references incorrectly as per what the RFC says it should do.
EDIT:
Further clarification... I didn't want to go into detail about the use case, but I figure at this stage it's worth explaining. The XML document I have is signed, and in order to verify the signature, part of the check is that the pre-calculated digest in the SignedInfo element matches the run-time calculation.
In order for these two to match, the canonicalization MUST be identical at both ends of the process (which is the entire reason for c14n).
I have both attempted to verify the signature using the .NET XmlDocument, and SignedXml classes, which is when I see the failure, and also used a 3rd party component (not a nobody in the world of XML signatures and c14n, as they work with government bodies) and their implementation results in a different c14n byte array - and that DOES then verify. This just gives me the answer of what the byte array should be looking like before performing the digest calculation.
So, perhaps I've been using the wrong terminology about rendered strings and I should have framed my question about the bytes that are produced.
The raw XML bytes look like this (in a different example that shows the problem directly):

The output of the .NET XmlDocument, which does not work when trying to calculate the hash (note the replacement of the character entity to be a single CR byte):

And then the 3rd party component output that verifies successfully (Note the correct output of a &xD; character entity, as I previously tried to explain):


White spaces in xml are between tags, not the innertext.  You are looking at the innertext which get saved exactly has written.

Also, it is better to use LINQ to XML API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

@KenWhite Not sure I have misunderstood - but granted I don't think I explained myself too well. I've made an edit that adds some more examples to hopefully make my point a bit clearer.
